# Like button will not fire edge.create or edge.remove

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm very much a beginner....

I can't get `edge.create` or `edge.remove` to fire when a like button is clicked. I see others have posted this problem too, going back to 2011, with no solution I can see.

My code is as follows....

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
    function(response) {
        alert('You UNliked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

</script>
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/XXX" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You’re just to impatient … :-)

In your code, you don’t wait for the Facebook SDK to load, which is done asynchronously the way you put it in your code. So when FB.Event.subscribe is called, the SDK is not yet initialized, and so that just fails. (Does it fail silently, or did you just forget to look into your browsers error console …?)

Put the code following the loading of the SDK into a window.fbAsyncInit handler, like shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: That's great, I've got it working now, thanks! I did see the code in the link and try it before. Howevere this time I put the edge.create and edge.remove sections in where it says " // Additional initialization code here" and it works this time thanks to your prompt to put it "into a window.fbAsyncinit handler"