# Catch 'like it' event on FP Page Plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an fb-page plugin on sidebar, it is coded like that:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/XXX" data-width="300" data-height="200" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/XXX"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/XXX">XXX</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

Is it possible to catch event when someone click on 'Like It' button?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005569/like-button-of-facebook-will-not-fire-edge-create-or-edge-remove-in-web-page

Comment: @RayonDabre In this solution I have to use 'appID' which I don't have because I am only developing webpage, not facebook app.

Comment: does not matter, you have to create an app for this. see my answer. "facebook app" does not mean it has to be "on facebook". external websites can also use facebook apps - for your case, it´s required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(url, html_element) {
    //like button clicked
});
```

Of course you have to create an App for this and include the JavaScript SDK in your page. More information about that, in case you don´t know already:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Make sure you use `FB.Event.subscribe` right after `FB.init`.